# How to replace characters in a text box as a user is typing in it? (in c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, textbox

Ok, what I have going on is a textbox that has been filled with some text depending on what was selected from a listbox.

say the textbox looks like this:

```
blah blah ??? as?f
```

what I need to figure out how to do is whenever the user clicks in the textbox and deletes a "?" character, I would like to replace that character with an * and then whenever they try to delete the * it will be replaced by a "?" , so that the end result will look something like

```
blah blah **? as*f
```

if they deleted all but one "?".

No matter how long I have searched online I cannot seem to find anything similar.. the closest thing I have found is this question - [Determine when and which character is added or deleted in a Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574942/determine-when-and-which-character-is-added-or-deleted-in-a-text-box)

But that doesnt really help for what I am trying to do.. if anyone has a good idea on where to start looking or even how to do it I would be very greatfull!

thanks in advance!

EDIT: Yes, this is for a Windows Form application, sorry i forgot to specify that. O.o

Comment: Ya sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event and bypass default handling. The event handler can look like the following:

```
public void OnKeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   char[] text = textBox.Text.ToCharArray();
   int pos = textBox.SelectionStart;

   switch (e.KeyCode)
   {
       case Keys.Back: if (pos == 0) return; pos --; break;
       case Keys.Delete: if (pos == text.Length) return; break;
       default: return;
   }

   switch (text[pos])
   {
       case '?': text[pos] = '*'; break;
       case '*': text[pos] = '?'; break;
       default: return;
   }
   textBox.Text = new String(text);
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

You may also want to add checks for modifier keys, adjust cursor position, and implement custom behavior when text is selected, if needed.

Comment: This almost works. Whenever I added the line of code "textBox.selectionStart = pos;" to put the cursor back where it was, it will delete the ? fine, and add the * fine, but it will for some reason delete an extra ?.. two ?'s will be deleted and one * will appear from one backspace press.... however pressing delete instead of backspace seems to work just fine and puts the cursor back where it should be without deleting anything extra.. I have put a breakpoint on every single line of my keydown even and it shows "text" as being correct at every step... ><

Comment: Is there another handler that processes backspace? You can try disabling backspace in this handler to see if it still goes through. Also, listening to TextChanged event may help to debug it.

Comment: This is the method im going to use, even though i cannot fix that error right now i will look around and see what i can figure out. thanks for the push in the right direction though!

Answer (score 2):

Store textbox.Text in some string, after each key press (textbox.KeyPress) by comparing saved string with text inside textbox, find out if '?' was deleted, if it was insert '*' into textbox text on the right place.

```
//get indexes of all '?'
list<int> charlist = new list<int>();
string buff = textbox.Text;
for(int c = 0; c< buff.length, c++)
{
    if (buff[c] == '?')
    {
        charlist.add(c)
    }
}
//inside keypress event
foreach(int c in charlist)
{
    if (textbox.Text[c] != '?')
    {
        textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(c, "*");
    }
}
```