# Identify the changed character and the position in windows phone7 Textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In windows phone7, I just need to track the changed character and changed position(index) in the textbox. I am struggling to find any property in the `TextChanged Event`.

I found the this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574942/determine-when-and-which-character-is-added-or-deleted-in-a-text-box), which is a similar question, but it works fine only with the WPF applications as `e.Changes` property is not available here in WP7.

Would be really grateful if someone can give an Idea. Thanks inadvance....!!!!

Comment: What is the signature of your textboxchanged event.

Comment: Do you mean parameters?    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

Comment: When this event is fired, look for e Properties and methods.

Comment: yes, I did that. I will add a screen shot of what I can see when I check for properties in e. I just check in a wpf textbox and it shows that property. But here it wasn't. Can't beleive as both should refering to properties of TextChangedEventArgs...

Comment: TextChangedEventArgs of SilverLight and .Net Framework 4.0 are different. Check TextChangedEventArgs of SilverLight - (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs(v=vs.95).aspx) and .Net Framework 4.0. - (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.aspx)

Comment: Ah yes, That's why the "Changes" property is not there. In this case I don't have a way to track which charater/characters changed in the textbox. Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Comment: In that case you have to create your own logic. Like when each value changes put it in a string say old_string. When this event is fired compared old_string with textbox value.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, 'll check for an awn logic then. Thanks.