# how can i change the password character of the textbox during runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have my log-in form and under that there's also the "Change Password" my teacher recommended me that if I write my old password in the old password textbox i'll see the characters, but if I leave that textbox and go to the new password textbox the characters should turn into "*".

How can I make that possible ?

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain your question more? I don't understand.

Comment: i have two textboxes in a form, if I type on the 1st textbox i can see all the characters I typed, but if I leave that textbox and type on the 2nd textbox all the characters on the 1st textbox become "*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, by convention there's no need to do this. The only reason that happens on mobile devices is that it's very easy to type wrong characters on tiny keyboards with large fingers. Getting a chance to quickly preview the last typed character is highly desirable. On a WinForms app I've never come across that usability. But, if you really want to do it, you'll need to create a custom control. The problem is that the PasswordChar property will mask all characters, not just all but the last one.

You could perhaps inherit from TextBox and add a property called TimedPasswordChar. Then subscribe to the ValueChanged event. In this handler, if TimedPasswordChar is not null or empty then start a Timer object with a 1000ms interval. In the Tick event handler, stop the timer on the first line the convert the last character to the TimedPasswordChar. Bear in mind though that you will need to add each character you switch to the TimedPasswordChar to a private member variable holding the actual password. I'd suggest using System.Security.SecureString given it's a password.

Just before you convert the last char to the TimedPasswordChar then add the entered value with .AppendChar(...).

One point that complicates it though is if the user edits the string.  You need to monitor which string has been edited and then use .RemoveAt(...) on the secure string to keep it in sync.

Comment: Also see this for details on the TextChanged event regarding tracking edits.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574942/determine-when-and-which-character-is-added-or-deleted-in-a-text-box

Comment: thank you . i think i get it 

it'll help more

Comment: Happy to help out further if you need it.  Keep in touch.

Comment: it works :)
Maraming Salamat (tagalog language of Thank you)

Comment: No worries.  By the way, can you please mark my response as answering your question?  Also perhaps vote on the answer?

Comment: sorry but i can't. . voting an answer needs 15 reputations, i'm a newbie